# how to search for past conferences in academia

Tags: conference

It's necessary to know what conferences happened in the past to know a field or a city. I don't mean proceedings but just where the conferences were held etc. I need this for metadata and statistics as well as for telling if a conference organizer is authentic or reputatable etc. Where can one search past conferences? Most sites show upcoming ones only.

Comment: What do you mean by past conferences? Do you mean "proceedings"? then use Google Scholar, the publisher search engine or any publication index. Do you mean "where the conference was held, which hotel, etc.? Then why? Do you mean metadata and statistics? You might find them in the Preface of the respective proceedings

Comment: The wording here is very unclear, particularly that first sentence. Can you reword that?

Comment: I don't understand why it is "necessary". Can you elaborate?

Comment: I read the question to be "Where can one search [for] past conferences?", but the first sentence understandably confuses people. OP, can you please clarify - I will edit my answer in case I misunderstood your question.

Comment: i'm sorry for the confusion and just reedited

Comment: I'm not sure why this question concerns you. The organizers will usually be some learned society/professional body or a university graduate school related to that field of research. Sometimes companies in an industry (or some body representing them) may organize a conference. Details like venue, city, etc are normally in the proceedings. If you only want to reference a "notable" conference, e.g. a laser physics conference at Paris in 1990, then you have to examine the proceedings, review the notable contributors and evaluate its "standard" w.r.t. what you regard as adequate for your own work.

Answer (score 2):

There is, in general, not one site where it's possible to search for past conferences.

Nevertheless, you have a number of options to collect information about past conferences. However, none of them will provide you with an exhaustive list.

- Conference series in which iterations happen regularly (e.g., yearly) often have links to previous editions on the webpage of the upcoming edition.
- The webpages of professional societies may contain a calendar that lists past events.
- Some researchers publish talk slides on their personal webpages. If a sufficient number of researchers in a field do so, this gives a fairly comprehensive overview.
- Talk to your peers and ask which conferences they attended in the past.
- If your field is based around conference proceedings, have a look where relevant papers were published in.

Comment: I concur; looking for unpublished abstracts from past meetings is just labor intensive detective work; there's no quick fix

Comment: i wish i knew how to look for unpublished abstracts from past meetings